# Angular http post params

Tags: angular, parameters, http-post

I'm sendind a post request to the rest api like this

```
this._http.post(full, this.user, this.options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(success => {
        this.onSuccess(success);
      }, error => {
        this.onError(error);
      });
```

The request work perfectly but i'm getting a bad response from the server because the parameters are sending this way:
[image]

Already tried with JSON.stringify and does not make a change.

How can i format the data?
Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks in advance.

This is the declaration

```
public user: any;
```

and within the constructor:

```
this.user = {
      "email: null,
      "password": null,
      "remember": false
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code for the User model?

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh email, password and remember.

Comment: I understand. Can I see the code where you declare it?

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh Edited the question with the declaration of the variable and the asignation in the constructor.

Comment: Well the only idea I have is to try give your user actual type, e.g. declare a class User with `{ email: string; password: string; remember: boolean }` and constructor. The construct your class and pass it to http.post. Also I'd check request content-type. What software you use to check parameters format? I've never seen such issue before..

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh I used the browser console to check. And compare it to another app using the same api. I will try your solution and I'll respond asap.

Comment: How does the user look like, when console logging `this.user` just before doing the post request?

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh The problem was the format, i have to fixed manually

Answer (score 0):

Convert the response into json using `map` operator in rxjs

```
this._http.post(full, this.user, this.options)
          .map(res=> res.json())
          .toPromise()
          .then(success => { },
                error => {}
          );
```

Comment: Nope, that does'nt change the parameters format. @Aravind

Comment: I didnt get you can you elaborate?

Comment: The parameters that i'm sending with the post request are bad formated, like in the image. I get that from the console, and because that bad formated the server rejects the request with status 400 @Aravind